# Package control_msgs was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: ros-groovy, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install the dynamixel_controllers package in Groovy on a 12.04 system.
When 'rosmake'-ing the dynamixel nodes... I receive this error:

`Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only dynamixel_controllers Package control_msgs was not found in the pkg-config search path.  Perhaps you should add the directory containing 'control_msgs.pc'  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable  No package 'control_msgs' found`

Now, I have built the 'control_msgs' package and can roscd to "control_msgs". When looking at the pkg-config folder in /opt/ros/groovy/lib/pkgconfig" folder, I do not see a 'control_msgs.pc' file, like I believe I should.
Should there be one there?
If not, why wouldn't it have been built if in fact the 'control_msgs' package was made like it says it was...?

Any help is appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67737/package-control_msgs-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path/) by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-07-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ryan Steindl](https://answers.ros.org/users/14516/ryan-steindl/) on 2014-05-06**:
I have stumbled across this problem did you ever find a solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did yes... but it's been a very long time. I'm sorry that I forgot to come back and mark my solution!
It most likely had to do with a `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` issue... but I'm sorry. I can't be sure.

---

Originally posted by [joe.s](https://answers.ros.org/users/3410/joe.s/) with karma: 162 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0